# Specifying the body content in a post using requests(python)

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have been using fiddler to inspect an http post that an application makes and then trying to replicate that post using requests in python.

The link I am posting to: http://www.example.com/ws/for/250/buy

Now in fiddler I can clearly see the headers which are easy to replicate using requests. However when I look in textview on fiddler I see this :

tuples=4,421&flows=undefined

To replicate that I think I need to use the data parameter which I found on the docs, however I am not sure how to write this in python? As in do I do it as a dictionary and split it up according to the & sign, or do i have to specify it a a string, etc?

My current code

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/ws/for/250/buy'
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1003.1 Safari/535.19 Awesomium/1.7.1',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'Accept-Charset': 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
    }
r6 = requests.post(url, headers = headers, verify = False)
```

Comment: So what does your current Python code look like?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), `requests.post` takes a `data` keyword which accepts, I presume, a dict of arguments to post. Where's yours?

Comment: Did you read my question? I dont know how to structure the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/ws/for/250/buy'
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1003.1 Safari/535.19 Awesomium/1.7.1',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'Accept-Charset': 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
    }
r6 = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False, data={'tuples': '4,421', 'flows': 'undefined'})
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

You provide a dictionary to the `data` argument:

```
r = requests.post(url, data={'tuples': '4,421', 'flows': 'undefined'})
```